# Two decimal float changing to many decimals in cell

Tags: c#, excel, floating-point, epplus, namevaluecollection

I have a value in a NameValueCollection that is .22.  That value is loaded into a float `fValue`.

The value is fValue=0.22 in debug, when it is written into Excel.

```
InvoiceWs.Cells["I" + iRow.ToString()].Style.Numberformat.Format = "$#,##0.00";
fValue = float.Parse(nvcUnitPrice["LG3000"].ToString());
InvoiceWs.Cells["I" + iRow.ToString()].Value = fValue;
```

When I open the Excel file, I see that the value is 0.219999998807907 and I am unable to figure out what is going on.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: why don't you use decimal for prices https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx. just a thought

Comment: Instead of Parsing the value to Float, can you use string for assignation?

Comment: @vbouk.. That did it. Thank you.  If you post that as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: @Martin If I use the string it writes the string to Excel and then it says that there is a number stored as a string and it won't work for calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working with prices you should use the decimal type. From msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx. Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point numbers only have a certain amount of precision. The closest number to 0.22 that can be represented is what you see in your table. You best bet is to use a different type such as `decimal` for `fValue` that doesn't suffer from such impecision.

Edit: If you enter `0.22` [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), you can see what I mean.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info on floats. Need to study up on those before I try to use them again. When researching I had read that some issues may have come from Excel being designed around IEEE754. Thanks for the info. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113